# LM5134.MOSFET driver Spice model not working in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, mosfet-driver

I downloaded the Spice model of the LM5134 MOSFET driver from the download page, created a symbol and created a schematic to test the model. You can download the zip archive containing the schematic, model and symbol [here](http://hotfile.mobi/fyxschz).

In the following I attached a screenshot from the schematic and a graph, which shows the voltage over time of the LM5134 pin OUT.

In my opinion, the graph should show an output of 12 volts and not ~0V. Since I'm new to LTspice I'm not sure that I implemented the model correctly. Could somebody please review my model?

[image: Screenshot from the schematic and a graph, which shows the voltage over time of the LM5134 pin OUT]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all why do you short the output pin via R1 resistor?

In LTspice \$10m\$ is interpreted as \$10m \Omega = 0.01\Omega \$.

Also we can find in data-sheet this information: 
[image] 
In your circuit \$V_{DD} = 12\$ therefore \$Vin > 0.67*12V = 8.04V \$

LM5134**B** is a TTL version

After I fix this the simulation look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I have changed the model and it is working now.